# How to show additional details in shopify admin order as shown in the given image?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

i want to add additional details into orders section in admin dashboard like the image below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLPg2.png)

Comment: Take a look here, it will help you, [custom order attributes](https://ui-elements-generator.myshopify.com/pages/cart-attribute) int Shopify order.

Comment: I guess this app does something like this as well, take a look https://apps.shopify.com/admin-by-eshopadmin

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it directly, Shopify order detail backend is closed, you can not add custom fields even a simple link , BUT, indirectly you can create a Shopify add, to grab your data and store in the order as a "note" (simple plain text), or create a app for custom order listing with all your required stuff